# Incremental data-dumps instead of the whole thing

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

Would it be possible to generate and release incremental data dumps (perhaps in addition to the full dumps)?

The reason being, obviously, they are getting quite large to download and they'll only grow. I  also understand there's quite a bit of technical difficulty in creating an incremental dump.

EDIT: See my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323837) on SO

Comment: Applying incremental updates doesn't sound like a cake-walk either.

Comment: Incremental updates don't sound hard to me. Just make a full dump and run a program that creates a delta file from the two xml files.