# What would cause a question to disappear completely?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The question [Why do people think functional programming will catch on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411290) has disappeared completely from SO. Going there gives me a 404 error (and I have 20k+). What gives?

Migrated questions like [What real life bad habits has programming given you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432) will take me to the new site, and it shows me a 404 **on the new site** since apparently it's been deleted from there as well and I don't have 10k on Programmers. But at least I know it's been migrated.

Comment: And: the 404 of your second example actually nicely tells you what happened: *This question was removed from Programmers - Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation.* Not so much for your first example indeed.

Comment: Where did you find that first link?

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F411290%22

Comment: @Shog9: I think because this page linked to it: http://www.stumbleupon.com/stumbler/Rich121/10/

Comment: This is really strange. 411283,411284,411286,41128 and others are missing, too. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114023/

Comment: Those all exist, @genesis. Try plugging them in at the end of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/` (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128) and notice how they still exist. They're *answers*...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your first question was merged with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504/why-functional-languages/). Originally, merging *completely destroyed* the source of the merge. Not soft-deleted, *destroyed*. This was... horrible. [So it was changed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16437/when-merging-questions-leave-the-duplicate-one-as-a-placeholder) Now when a question is merged, the source is left as a stub with no answers, and when that is deleted, the site will automatically redirect to the destination.

Unfortunately, links to questions merged before the current "stub" feature was implemented remain forever broken.

Comment: They don't have to remain *forever* broken... This could be fixed by manually regenerating the "stub." This probably won't ever be done, but still...

Comment: Ehm, and what about others missing? [were they all merged](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/114023/) ?

Comment: You should consider suggesting that as a feature-request, although I'm not sure enough information remains for it to be done in all cases. See: "destroyed" and "horrible".

Comment: @genesis: those aren't missing, they're soft-deleted in the normal fashion (and hence aren't included in the data-dumps). Also, they're mostly answers.

Comment: If I knew what the internals of merging are (eg: do merged answers retain their IDs?), I think I can help find these "missing" merges. I downloaded **all** data dumps and I am in the process of finding [changes between the sets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105164/incremental-data-dumps-instead-of-the-whole-thing) so I could try to figure out what went where.

Comment: @Shog9: Damn. I have forgotten soft-deleted posts aren't included in dumps. Is there any chance to get 10k data dump ?

Comment: That should be fairly straightforward, @Null: answer IDs don't change; merging simply re-parents them. So if the parent ID changes from one dump to the next, that answer has been merged into another question. Anything merged before ~[June 4, 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-do-migrated-questions-lack-redirection-via-http-response-status-code-301-mov/52585#52585) will lack a stub - so the previous parentID should now be MIA.

Comment: @genesis: [highly unlikely.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33568/data-dump-should-include-deleted-posts)

Comment: @Shog9 Are stubs for questions merged after the change present in the datadump (if they haven't been deleted)?

Comment: @Null: probably. But I wouldn't depend on that for anything more than a sanity-check, since as you note they *won't* be if they *have* been deleted. I assume you're looking for a way to determine if a stub is needed for a given question ID: querying the site and checking the status code (redirect vs not found) is the only way to be sure.